# SQL if statement within WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to do the following query, how can I implement it?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE routeNum LIKE 'N10%' 
-->if no rows return, WHERE clause change to routeName LIKE '&something%'
```

Comment: you want to use CASE statement, check this forum or google for SQL Case statement in where clause

Comment: @user..can you furthur exlpain your requirement?

Comment: @user..are you using mysql or sqlserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 2 AS 'INDEX', * FROM table WHERE routeNum LIKE 'N10%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS 'INDEX', * FROM table WHERE routeNum LIKE '&something%'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.INDEX = (SELECT MAX(INDEX) FROM CTE)
```

As you have to choose between two result sets, you will need two queries, which will return two different sets and then, based on the 'index' which corresponds to the query that has run, you choose how to display your results.

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63895a/9) demo.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM routes 
   WHERE routeNum LIKE 'N10%'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM routes 
 WHERE routeNum LIKE 'something else%'
   AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM cte
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/508c3/4)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tmp AS
(
SELECT t.*, 
CASE 
    WHEN routeNum LIKE 'N10%' THEN 1 
    WHEN routeNum LIKE '&something%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END AS q
FROM table t
)

SELECT * FROM tmp t
WHERE q = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp WHERE q = 1 ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```